# Data will not load into the popup using the Basic Viewer template for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, json

I have downloaded the zip file for the Basic Map Viewer (https://github.com/Esri/Viewer) in ArcGIS and am trying to configure the layers to have popups.  I've reviewed some of the code behind other applications and have copied the code but have replaced the URLs with my rest services and inserted my fields as well.  However, when I launch the application, the popup remains blank.  It's showing up, but the data from our server isn't loading in the popup.

This is what I have for the code for one layer:

```
{
              "url": "http://giswebvm1:81/arcgis/rest/services/INTER_DP/ev_health/MapServer/0",
              "visibility": false,
              "title": "Food Establishments",
              "popupInfo": {
                  "title": "{Name}",
                  "fieldInfos": [
                  {
                      "fieldname": "Est_No",
                      "label": "Establishment Number",
                      "tooltip": "",
                      "visible": true,
                      "stringFieldOption": "textbox"
                  },
                  {
                      "fieldname": "Name",
                      "label": "Establishment Name",
                      "tooltip": "",
                      "visible": true,
                      "stringFieldOption": "textbox"
                  },
                  ],
                  "description": null,
                  "showAttachments": true,
                  "mediaInfos": []
              }
            },
```

Does anyone know why the popup isn't loading?

[image: It looks like this]

[image: Here is the layer service]

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to make clear whether you are this is the [Basic Map Viewer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f232cac140a8495f9990cc9d2bb66dd9) that you are using?  It seems to have been renamed to Classic Viewer.

Comment: Do those fields definitely exist on the layer? When you head to http://giswebvm1:81/arcgis/rest/services/INTER_DP/ev_health/MapServer/0 do you see `Est_No` and `Name` listed in the Fields section?

Comment: Yes.  I made sure and I even tried it with a few different fields that are included in the layer.

Answer (score 1):

"fieldname" is case sensitive. Correct key name is "fieldName". (uppercase N)

See this example for fieldInfos.

http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/items/db7b51510a84452ea2113eceb9a1bfd0/data?f=pjson

Comment: I deleted the stringFieldOption and the popup has not changed.  I made sure that all of the names that are in "fieldname" are exactly as I have them in our server.  Would it be easier if you could see that layer information (metadata)?

Comment: Yes that would help

Comment: I added it as an image.  Hopefully you can see this if you zoom in.  Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: corrected my answer. correct fieldname to fieldName